# Cannot use Ember associations

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-data, sails.js

I have been trying to make this work for several days now. I cannot access a profile object from its associated user object. I have the latest versions of Ember and ember-data

```
Ember-data: 1.0.0-beta15
Ember: 1.10.0 production
```

I have a simple table view that lists my users and a couple properties. Here is the view:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="users/verification-candidates">
    <div class="small-12 column">
        <h1>Candidates for Verification</h>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>System ID</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Created At</th>
            <th>Legal First Name</th>
            <th>Legal Last Name</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
            {{#each user in model itemController="candidate" }}
             <tr>
               <td> {{ user.id }}</td>
               <td> {{ user.email }}</td>
               <td>{{ user.created_at }}</td>
               <td>{{ user.legal_first_name }}</td>
               <td>{{ user.legal_last_name }}</td>
               <td><button id="verify" {{ action "markVerified" }}>Verify</button></td>
               <td><button id="disable" {{ action "markDisabled" }}>Disable</button></td>
             </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </table>
    </div>
</script>
```

The models are like so:

```
App.Profile = DS.Model.extend({
        user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
        incognito_name : DS.attr('string'),
        advisor_id : DS.attr('number'),
        created_at : DS.attr('date'),
        //etc..

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    profile: DS.belongsTo('profile',{ async: true }),
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    sign_in_count: DS.attr('number'),
    last_sign_in_at: DS.attr('date'),
    //etc...
```

I am using the rest adapter:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://localhost:1337',
  defaultSerializer: 'json'
});
```

Pertinent routes:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('users', { path: '/users'}, function(){
        this.route('verification-candidates');
    });
    this.resource('profiles', { path: '/profiles' }, function(){
    })
});

App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('user');
    }
});

App.ProfilesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
      return this.store.find('profile');
    }
})

App.UsersVerificationCandidatesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function(){
        var items =  this.store.find('user', { role: "advisor", disabled: false, is_verified: false });

        return items;
    },

})
```

My server is a sails.js back end, which accesses a database created by a Rails application.

I want to alter the profile in this object controller, but cannot access it in any meaningful form:

```
App.CandidateController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
      markVerified: function(){
          var user = this.get('model');
          var profile = user.get('profile');
          console.log(profile);  //output 1
          console.log(profile.incognito_name); //output 2
    }
  }
});
```

The output2 is undefined. Output 1 gives me some sort of object with properties __nextSuper, __ember_meta, a bunch of other things,  isFulfilled, and content. But, no object properties from the model definition. This appears to be a promisearray,but, I thought this was the way to get a related object. Meanwhile, when I try to treat it as a PromiseArray, per [the documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.PromiseProxyMixin.html), i get null, like this:

```
App.CandidateController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
      markVerified: function(){
          var user = this.get('model');
          user.get('profile').then(function(content){
              console.log("promise content is " + content);
              //prints 'promise content is null'
          })
          //console.log(profile);
          //console.log(profile.incognito_name);

    }
  }
```

I am fairly certain all my back end server/client things are in order, as I can access the user objects and work with them on the page. I am thinking it may be related to how the profile relates to the user via advisor_id, but, I am so confused right now. I am very much at my wit's end.

Comment: where is the code that connects the candidate controller to the user model?

Comment: in other words, can you show your `CandidateRoute`?

Comment: If you haven't already, install Ember Inspector in Chrome or Firefox. You can use it to see if your models are loading and controller properties.

Comment: There is actually no CandidateRoute. The user objects come from the UsersVerificationCandidatesRoute. I'll add that.

Comment: can you throw this into jsbin and use mockjax? https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax

Comment: Here is the js bin link. I'm working on making the mockjax work in it. http://jsbin.com/jojuyi/2/

Comment: Well, I can't get it to work in JSBin. Then, uprooting a whole app and making it work in a different environment, using a foreign library, is a task on its own.

Comment: If there is no App.CandidateRoute, how are you setting up your App.CandidateController?

Comment: hey did you find an answer? I am encountering some problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766025/ember-js-association-access-backend-nodejs-mongoose